# How to fisheye effect create on video in android?

Tags: fisheye

I want to apply fisheye effect on video which is play in android device placed at sdcard of device, so if i open to play any selected video from sdcard its play with Fisheye effect on video in android device it is possible or not. If it is possible so please show me some snippet or hint to create fisheye effect on video. If it is not possible so please give me reason behind of this.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes i am trying to android media effect in android. But its not for it    i guess.